# Why doesn't the range of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ include negative numbers?

Tags: functions, square-numbers

It is definitely true that $\sqrt{9}$ is both $3$ and $-3$, and that $\sqrt{25}=-5,5$.

When I graph the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ its range is shown to be $y\geq0$.

Why doesn't its range include negative numbers?

Comment: Because the symbol $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is *defined* to mean "take the *nonnegative* square root of $\cdot$." Your first sentence is wrong. The solution set of $x^2=9$ is $\left\{\pm3\right\}$, but $\sqrt{9}=3$, period.

Comment: "It is definitely true" is always a bad argument. Most mathematicians define $\sqrt{\cdot}$ differently.

Comment: In particular, *functions* are, by definition, single-valued.

Comment: Also, the statement $\color{red}{\sqrt{25}=-5,5}$ is *patently absurd*. First, it is syntactically absurd: you can't list numbers using commas after equal signs. (When teachers write things like $x=1, 2$ they are being very naughty.) Second, it is semantically absurd: if $\sqrt{25}=5$ and $\sqrt{25}=-5$, then $5=-5$ (because $=$ is transitive). But $5$ isn't equal to $-5$.

Comment: The square root is different from the solution set of a quadratic. Also, if the range did include negative numbers, there will be two values of $y$ for one value of $x$. Since $f(x)=\sqrt x$ is a function, this is a contradiction.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Everybody knows that $x=a,b$ means "$x=a$ or $x=b$." That is pedantic without being helpful.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I disagree. It's not pedantic for an audience of middle or high school students. Writing $x=a, b$ can breed precisely the sort of confusion witnessed here. Your "everybody" means "everybody with enough training not to commit these kinds of elementary errors." But students *do* commit these errors. They aren't thinking about the semantics of the notation they use.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So, would you say that it is definitely true that "'it is definitely true' is always a bad argument"?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not "definitely true that $\sqrt 9$ is both $3$ and $-3$".

As the symbol is usually defined, $\sqrt 9$ means the *non-negative* number whose square is $9$. In other words, it means $3$.

$-3$ is a number whose square is $9$, but because $-3$ fails to be a *non-negative* number, it is not the value of $\sqrt 9$.

---

There are a few contexts where the $\sqrt{\cdots\vphantom x}$ notation is used not to denote a single number but the entire set of numbers whose square is "$\cdots$". Foremost this can be the case when complex numbers are involved. But this is still not the *usual* meaning of the symbol.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly elementary reason is that $f(x)=\pm\sqrt{x}$ is not a function.